# How to include special characters in RDLC report without t2embed error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am having issues getting special characters to appear in RDLC. More specifically the Spanish Accent characters such as :

```
Ñ
Á
Í
Ó
Ú
```

The error is : **System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'T2Embed': Access is denied**

It seems that GoDaddy does not have this extension and it is not being moved over during deployment. I have tried to manually transfer and different error messages appear. In case permissions was an issue, using the Plesk admin portal, the file T2Embed.dll was given full control permissions.

I can simply just add restrictions to prevent these characters from being entered in the first place, but since the audience of these reports are from a Spanish speaking country, I'd rather allow entry and just fix RDLC to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

that is Godaddy Issue with font embedding. Solution is set "Device info" to "Not embedding fonts". 
But, then your PDF is not showing proper characters on some devices. Android phones not showing unicode characters at all. I think we should change hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\t2embed.dll" file to your bin folder.